# Return products based on Seller ID - Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I've been doing some research and it seems that the `<MerchantId>` was deprecated a few years ago. Anything other than `"MerchantId"=>"Amazon"` returns `<MerchantId>Deprecated</MerchantId>`

Has anyone found a way to search by merchant?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this through AWS? I was searching this and looks like you need to use MWS (Marketplace Web Service) for this.